# Omit tasks from team planner

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

Is it possible to omit some tasks from being used in the calculation of a resources allocation percent.

I've looked at this a number of different ways but in short, I want to have a couple of tasks running in parallel that are assigned to one resource. However, I know that for this set of tasks, I want to calculate the resources allocation for only one task. To do this I'd like to remove the task from the resource allocation calculation.

I know I can do percentages but when the number of tasks goes up and down I don't want to have to change them as that task number changes.

**Question**
Is it possible to enter a task, the expected duration, assign one or more resources and on a one by one basis omit them from the resource allocation calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that was between a solution and a hack but it works for me.

This works well in the scenario below but is not guaranteed for other scenarios.

Summary Task
- [Time Block]: 10D
- Sub Task 1: 5D
- Sub Task 2: 5D
- Sub Task 3: 5D
- Sub Task 4: 5D

I'm comfortable with saying the summary task will take 10 days but I'm not comfortable with allocating time on a sub task basis. So I:
- Assign the resource to the Time Block task at 100%
- Assign the same resource to the sub tasks at 0%
- Ensure that the task type is "Fixed Duration"

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not.  You could swap resources with a resource that you set a large number of max units to avoid overallocation.  But the peak units are calculated based upon assignments to all tasks - you cannot omit some.